# Can I use Gensim doc2vec model for classification new documents?

Tags: classification, word2vec, gensim

Can I use Gensim doc2vec model for classification new documents via infer_vector? All my tests gave too bad results, even for big datasets (10GB utf-8 texts)...

Comment: Check out https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html